# One computer connects at 100Mbps, other computers connect at 1000Mbps

Tags: networking, ethernet, desktop, wired-networking

I have a client whose home PC is connecting to a wired ethernet connection at 100Mbps instead of 1Gbps/1000Mbps. The odd thing is that when I connect other devices, *they* connect at 1Gbps with no issues.

My troubleshooting steps thus far:

1. Connected two different laptops to the same end of the cable going into the trouble PC. Result=Both devices connect at 1Gbps.
2. Checked link speed settings on teh trouble PC by going to Start>Settings>Network & Internet Settings>Ethernet>Change adapter options>*network connection*>Properties>Configure>Link Speed>**Verified "Speed and Duplex" set to "Auto Negotiation**. Result=no change
3. Tried forcing 1Gbps speed on link. Result=Network connection now says "network cable unplugged".
4. Reverted to "Auto-Negotiate" on link speed. Result=Connection is back at 100Mbps/100Mbps.
5. Reboot system. Result=no change.
6. Reboot network router. Result=no change.
7. Renewed DHCP lease via CMD>ipfig /release>ipconfig /renew. Result=no change.
8. Checked router configuration to see if there were any settings specifically identifying or limiting the trouble PC. Result=Nothing in the router mentions the device at all, except for listing it as a currently connected (wired) device.
9. Updated the BIOS (it was running BIOS from 2013, so I updated it to the latest version from 2020). Result=no change.
10. Went to support.hp.com to get latest network driver and installed it. Result=no change.
11. Posting issue to online forums for community assistance.

I'm debating installing a PCIe network card to attempt to eliminate or isolate the problem to the on-board motherboard NIC, but that is added cost to me and doesn't really answer the problem if it appears in other similar systems.

Thanks in advance for the help!

System: HP ProDesk 800 G2 SFF
OS: Windows 10 20H2
NIC driver: Intel Ethernet Connection I217-LM, version 12.12.218.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AZ6s.png)

Comment: Try a different NIC. Even a USB 3.x Gigabit Ethernet dongle would do if you don't want to take the time to install a PCIe NIC. I've seen NICs have cracked solder joints where the 8P8C female connects to the board, causing some pins to have faulty connections. I've also seen bent pins inside the female connector that don't make good contact.

Comment: Forgot to say: If pins 1, 2, 3, and 6 are in good shape, but any other pins are faulty, you can get a solid 100BASE-TX connection but fail to make a 1000BASE-T connection. You've proven your cable to be good, but the fault may be inside the NIC; likely right at the 8P8C connector.

Comment: @Spiff I checked the cable with a tester and it showed all four pairs matching up correctly. I even re-terminated the RJ45 ends and connected the PC directly to the router port - Same result.

Comment: @Spiff I've ordered a PCIe NIC card and I'm going to try using that to bypass the MB on-board NIC. Thanks for your comments, though!